# Problems logging in to Yahoo using cURL in php

Tags: php, curl, authentication, yahoo

I am having problem logging in to Yahoo with the PHP code I have written. The code was working earlier, but for some reason it stopped working. It always shows Yahoo login page with my username at the top like, `Hi Sudhir` at the header as if I'm logged in already, along with my yahoo username, but displays password field and Login button again saying `Please Verify your password`.

Though I tried to resend the request once more taking the new form action `https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?`, but it keeps on displaying the same page. Following is my complete Yahoo login code.

Please suggest what am I doing wrong or am I missing something?

```
<?php
$yahooCalUrl = "http://calendar.yahoo.com";
$ch = curl_init($yahooCalUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies_new.txt");
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies_new.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$resCalUrl = curl_exec($ch);
//echo $resCalUrl;
$loginUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?";

//get the hidden values
$searchStr = "/name=\".u\" value=\"(.*?)\"/";
preg_match($searchStr, $resCalUrl, $matches);
$u = $matches[1];

$searchStr1 = "/name=\".challenge\" value=\"(.*?)\"/";
preg_match($searchStr1, $resCalUrl, $matches1);
$challenge = $matches1[1];

$searchStr2 = "/name=\".pd\" value=\"(.*?)\"/";
preg_match($searchStr2, $resCalUrl, $matches2);
$pd = $matches2[1];

$username = "my_yahoo_username";
$password = "my_yahoo_password";
//$mdPassword = md5($password);
//$finalPass = $mdPassword . $challenge;
//$hash = md5($finalPass);
//$finalHash = urlencode($hash);
$done = urlencode("http://calendar.yahoo.com");
$postFields = ".tries=1&.src=fpctx&.md5=&.hash=&.js=&.last=&promo=&.intl=us&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=".$u."&.v=0&.challenge=".$challenge."&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yahoo.com%2F&.pd=fpctx_ver%3D0%26c%3D%26ivt%3D%26sg%3D&pad=3&aad=3&login=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&.save=&passwd_raw=";
//$postFields = ".tries=1&.src=&.md5=&.hash=&.js=&.last=&promo=&.intl=us&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=".$u."&.v=0&.challenge=".$challenge."&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=1&.chkP=Y&.pd=".$pd."&pad=6&aad=6&.persistent=&.save=1&login=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&.done=".$done;
curl_setopt($ch, curlOPT_USERAGENT, $agent); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "my_cookies_new.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "my_cookies_new.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
$finalLoggedIn = curl_exec($ch);
echo $finalLoggedIn;

?>
```

Though I tried using the password hash, i.e. combining the dynamic channel value of Yahoo with my password, but it didn't work out that way either.

Comment: Perhaps a dumb question, but can you still login the "normal" way? Also, check what headers are being sent when you logon. Perhaps something has changed in their form!

Comment: The above code works fine in my local server, but when i upload it to live server, it does not work at all, always keeps on displaying the login page. I have a linux server in live. What could be the problem..? Please suggest

Comment: Please check if you have the same PHP.ini settings for both live and local. Please make sure you're also displaying all errors `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I checked the cookie file created during yahoo login, the cookie file is complete when i try it in local (i.e logs in successfully), but the cookie file in server has totally different data, and incomplete. Like the local servers cookie file is 1 KB but on live its only 307 bytes, so cookies are not being set properly when it comes to liver server. What could be the reason for this..?

Comment: There might be a small posibility that the IP-address of your live server has been blocked? Try to run your script on a different server and check if the problem still exists.

Comment: Tested to code uploading it to some other server also, but its the same, it always shows login page. Btw, i checked the curl versions, in localhost its 7.16 and in two live server its 7.21 & 7.19, so could it be the problem of libcurl different versions..?

Comment: Sudhir, great to hear. What solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like no one has responded to this. And I know its an annoying issue.

I see where you are setting the cookie name/jar... but not opening the file to read/write. The solution was more than likley to use `fopen()` on the file first...

```
$cookie_jar_file = "my_cookies_new.txt";
$fp = fopen($cookie_jar_file, "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar_file);
```

Also:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

Do not forget to close the opened file and delete it at the end of your script.

```
fclose($fp);

unlink($cookie_jar_file);
```

Hope this helps someone. 
Here is how I would do it though:

1: Get the info from Yahoo that wou will need.

```
// *********************************************************************************************
// GET CHALLENGE
// *********************************************************************************************
    $cs = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://m.google.com/");
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?");
//  curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=".$id."&passwd=".$pass."&.src=&.tries=5&.bypass=&.partner=&.md5=&.hash=&.intl=us&.tries=1&.challenge=ydKtXwwZarNeRMeAufKa56.oJqaO&.u=dmvmk8p231bpr&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=0&.v=0&.chkP=N&.last=&.done=http://m.yahoo.com/w/ygo-mail/");
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar_file);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar_file);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
//  curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
//  curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

    $y_login_page = curl_exec($cs); 
    //print $y_login_page;
    curl_close($cs);


$proceed = true;


if(preg_match("/type=\"hidden\" name=\".challenge\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $y_login_page, $challenge)){
    print "<PRE>";
    print_r($challenge);
    print"</PRE>";
    print "FOUND CHALLENGE STRING<BR>";
    $chal = $challenge[1];
}
else {
    print "\nNO CHALLENGE STRING";
    $proceed = false;
}
if(preg_match("/type=\"hidden\" name=\".u\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $y_login_page, $array_u)){
    print "<PRE>";
    print_r($array_u);
    print"</PRE>";
    print "FOUND .U STRING<BR>";
    $u = $array_u[1];
}
else {
    print "\nNO U STRING";
    $proceed = false;
}
if(preg_match("/type=\"hidden\" name=\".pd\" value=\"(.*?)\"/", $y_login_page, $array_pd)){
    print "<PRE>";
    print_r($array_pd);
    print"</PRE>";
    print "FOUND .PD STRING<BR>";
    $pd = $array_pd[1];
}

if(preg_match("/ts=(.*?)&/", $y_login_page, $array_ts)){
    print "<PRE>";
    print_r($array_ts);
    print"</PRE>";
    print "FOUND TIME STAMP STRING<BR>";
    $xts = $array_ts[1];
}
```

Then Use The Info You Just Collected With Your Username And Pass To Login.

```
// *********************************************************************************************
// CURL SESSION #1:  AUTHENTICATE THE USER ID ON YAHOO'S SERVER
// *********************************************************************************************
$cs = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://m.google.com/");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_URL, "http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?");//http://login.yahoo.com/config/login?
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ".tries=1&.src=&.md5=&.hash=&.js=&.last=&promo=&.intl=us&.lang=en-US&.bypass=&.partner=&.u=".$u."&.v=0&.challenge=".$chal."&.yplus=&.emailCode=&pkg=&stepid=&.ev=&hasMsgr=0&.chkP=Y&.done=http://calendar.yahoo.com&.pd=".$pd."&.ws=0&.cp=0&nr=0&pad=5&aad=5&login=".$id."&passwd=".$pass."&.persistent=y&.save=");
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_jar_file);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_jar_file);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
//curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
//curl_setopt($cs, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy); 
$y_login_page = curl_exec($cs); 
print $y_login_page;
```

The PostFeilds here has a field named "done".

Set that to `done=http://calendar.yahoo.com`

Or wherever you want to go after logging in.