# log into yahoo using curl getting javascript must be enable error

Tags: php, curl

I want to login into the yahoo using php curl. I have parsed the yahoo login page and extracted all the fields but when i login into the yahoo using these fields then getting javascript must be enable into your browser error. I just followed this link.

[Problems logging in to Yahoo using cURL in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429681/problems-logging-in-to-yahoo-using-curl-in-php)

Comment: That answer is 2 years old, Yahoo has obviously updated their login page and now it requires Javascript. Curl doesn't have a Javascript interpreter.

Comment: so we don't have any way to login into yahoo using curl or some other api.

Answer (score 0):

use the yahoo API:
http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html

This should be your answer!